# SQL statement to check for empty string - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a `WHERE` clause for where a certain string variable is not null or empty. The problem I am running into is that certain non-empty strings equal the `N''` literal. For instance:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = N'㴆';
select case when @str = N'' then 1 else 0 end;
```

Yields 1. From what I can gather on [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%B4%86), this particular unicode character is a pictograph for submerging something, which is not semantically equal to an empty string. Also, the string length is 1, at least in T-SQL.

Is there a better (accurate) way to check a T-SQL variable for the empty string?

Comment: A "no value" entry should be `NULL`. Then it is really easy to check: `@str is not null ...`

Comment: The application is question uses `NULL` to indicate "Do not modify this field" and `N''` to indicate "Update this value to NULL". The design is intentional so that fields not needing modification can be omitted from data modification messages.

Comment: Do you mean: check if the value of nvarchar is ANSI STD?

Comment: Yields 1 with what database? SQLite 3, Postgres 9.6, and MySQL 5.7 all work with `select case when N'㴆' = N'' then 1 else 0 end;` (SQLite doesn't support N literals, but it works without it) Have you checked what's in `@str`?

Comment: @Schwern Microsoft SQL Server 2008 through 2016 all yield 1. The value of `@str` is the actual character in the post. I'm guessing this is a Microsoft problem.

Comment: @JesanFafon Do you still get a problem without the intermediate variable? `select case when N'㴆' = N'' then 1 else 0 end;`? Also, check your collation settings. And is it just that character? What about others?

Comment: @Schwern The collation settings are the SQL Server defaults for US English. The issue appears with or without the intermediate variable. I have not tested other characters yet.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether the field in question is a dependent on some sort of user input and hence the Char is N'㴆' , can be expected?
Or is you question more theoretical?

Comment: The question is more theoretical. I am interested in being able to assume that the code is correct for all strings possible in Unicode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a blog, https://bbzippo.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/sql-server-collations-and-string-comparison-issues/

which explained that

> The problem is because the “default” collation setting
>   (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) for SQL Server cannot properly compare
>   Unicode strings that contain so called Supplementary Characters
>   (4-byte characters).

A fix is to use a collation that doesn't have problems with the supplementary characters. For example:

```
select case when N'㴆' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS = N'' then 1 else 0 end;
```

will return 0. See the blog for more examples.

Since you are comparing to the empty string, another solution would be to test the string length.

```
declare @str1 nvarchar(max) =N'㴆';
select case when len(@str1) = 0 then 1 else 0 end;
```

This will return 0 as expected.

This also yields 0 when the string is null.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to devio's comment, I dug a bit deeper and found a comment from Erland Sommarskog https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/X8UhQaP9KF0

that in addition to not supporting Supplementary Characters, the Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation doesn't handle new Unicode characters correctly. So I'm guessing that the 㴆 character is a new Unicode character.

Specifying the collation `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` will also fix this issue.

Comment: You are correct regarding collations, but `select DATALENGTH(@str)` returns 2, CAST AS VARBINARY gives `U+3D06`, therefore not a supplementary character.